# VPC Connectors does not work in Montreal (northamerica-northeast1)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpc-peering

Since yesterday our VPC connectors (from region northamerica-northeast1 to networks in the same region) have not been working. When I review the connector status it shows the message: The connector is in bad condition; manual removal is recommended.

The VPC connectors in other regions, like us-east1, are working well.

Does anyone else have the same problem? What can I do?

Comment: Does this have to do with a cloud provider? Which one?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for repoly. The Cloud provider is Google.

Comment: Please add more details to your case and use this command to have further information about the error: `gcloud compute networks vpc-access connectors create [CONNECTOR_NAME] \
--network [VPC_NETWORK] \
--region [REGION] \
--range [IP_RANGE]
--verbosity debug`. You can also check their official [troubleshooting guide](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#troubleshooting) for VPC.

Comment: Alex, thanks for reply. I executed the command with following Results:.

Comment: C:\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud compute networks vpc-access connectors create xxxx-dev-vpc-connector-3 --network xxxx-dev-resources-vpc-montreal --region northamerica-northeast1 --range 10.110.26.0/28 --verbosity debug
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.compute.networks.vpc-access.connectors.create] with arguments: [--network: "xxxx-dev-resources-vpc-montreal", --range: "10.110.26.0/28", --region: "northamerica-northeast1", --verbosity: "debug", CONNECTOR: "xxxx-dev-vpc-connector-3"]
DEBUG: Making request: POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token

Comment: DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.googleapis.com:443
DEBUG: https://www.googleapis.com:443 "POST /oauth2/v4/token HTTP/1.1" 200 None
Create request issued for: [xxxx-dev-vpc-connector-3]
Waiting for operation [projects/xxxx-dev-resources/locations/northamerica-northeast1/operations/886df849-e983-4a92-bbaa-cd5605a8a738] to complete
...failed.
DEBUG: (gcloud.compute.networks.vpc-access.connectors.create) {
  "code": 13,
  "message": "An internal error occurred: Failed to create a VPC Access connector. Please delete the connector manually."

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\cli.py", line 983, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "C:\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\backend.py", line 808, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)

Comment: File "C:\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\command_lib\util\apis\yaml_command_translator.py", line 316, in Run
    request_string=request_string)
  File "C:\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\command_lib\util\apis\yaml_command_translator.py", line 1087, in _HandleAsync
    operation_ref, resource_ref, extract_resource_result, args=args)

Comment: File "C:\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\command_lib\util\apis\yaml_command_translator.py", line 1100, in _WaitForOperation  self._GetDisplayName(resource_ref, args) if args else None))
  File "C:\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\api_lib\util\waiter.py", line 264, in WaitFor
    sleep_ms, _StatusUpdate)

Comment: File "C:\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\api_lib\util\waiter.py", line 326, in PollUntilDone
    sleep_ms=sleep_ms)
  File "C:\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\util\retry.py", line 229, in RetryOnResult
    if not should_retry(result, state):
  File "C:\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\api_lib\util\waiter.py", line 320, in _IsNotDone

Comment: return not poller.IsDone(operation)
  File "C:\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\command_lib\util\apis\yaml_command_translator.py", line 1274, in IsDone
    raise waiter.OperationError(SerializeError(error))
googlecloudsdk.api_lib.util.waiter.OperationError: {
  "code": 13,
  "message": "An internal error occurred: Failed to create a VPC Access connector. Please delete the connector manually."

Comment: ERROR: (gcloud.compute.networks.vpc-access.connectors.create) {
  "code": 13,
  "message": "An internal error occurred: Failed to create a VPC Access connector. Please delete the connector manually."
}    In a   troubleshooting guide  I couldn't find any reference to help us in order to solve the problem. Can you see something wrong that I am missing?. Thanks

Comment: Additional Info: 1) wit the same command I could create a VPC connnectors succesfully in regions: us-east1 and southamerica-east1. 2) The connector in region Montreal (that i am trying to re-create) was initially created one month ago, but from Decembre 17th it was over message: Please delete the connector manually. What's wrong in Montreal?

Comment: When adding details to your post, you can edit your original post and add it from there since adding it in the comment section have limits. I found several cases with the same issue as yours and the root cause is about character limitations on the application. As a workaround, please recreate the connectors with a short connector name and it should work fine.